# Sync sanity database to salesforce

Tags: salesforce, data-synchronization, sanity

I have some sites made with sanity. So I want to sync my sanity database to salesforce. If I get a better flow or idea or links it will help

Answer (score 1):

you need to create RestResource's in salesforce and then need to hit resource end point to create/update/delete data into salesforce.
It's pretty easy you can learn it from trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices